# execution context process of asynchronous functions in a try/catch statement

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, try-catch

```js
    async function foo() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://www.xxx.xxx");
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error!!: ", e);
      }
    }
    foo();
    console.log('111');
```

Assuming that there is a code like this, the execution result is

111 -> Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

And that's what happens when I think about the execution context process, depending on the code flow

1. When the foo function is called, the execution context of the foo function is created and added to the call stack.
2. When fetch ("https://www.xxx.xxx ") runs within the try block, the execution context of the fetch function is created and added to the call stack. This is when a network request is made in the background. The fetch function returns a Promise and the execution context of the fetch function is removed from the call stack.
3. subsequent actions after the await keyword are added to the micro-task queue.
4. The foo function ends, removing the execution context of the foo function from the call stack.
5. console.log ('111) is executed and "111" is output to the console.
6. Since the call stack is empty, subsequent operations after await that were queued in the micro-task queue are sequentially moved to the call stack and executed.
7. The fetch function's network request fails and a reject is called, causing Promise's status to be rejected.
8. How do you catch an error???

The try/catch statement is a little confusing.

In order for console.log ('111) to run, the call stack must be empty, but how does the catch in the foo function that has already ended get an error??

please help me!

Comment: "*subsequent actions after the await keyword are added to the micro-task queue.*" - no, that only happens once the promise is fulfilled or rejected, not before. And the action to execute depends on the resolution of the promise - it's either resuming the assignment expression with the `response` value or it's resuming the execution with an exception, which will be handled be the `try` block just like in a synchronous function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I just want to know the reason how the error can be output from the execution context perspective.

When the foo function is called, the execution context of the foo function is created and pushed to the call stack, and 111 output means that the execution context of the foo function has been removed from the call stack, so how can an error be detected in the catch statement inside a foo function

Comment: The "action after the await" keyword is to **resume** the execution context that got **suspended** earlier. It gets put back on the call stack. But that's not strictly related to catching exceptions. You could ask the same question for how it is possible that variables from before the `await` are still available afterwards, in the good (non-error) case as well.

Comment: Oh really? Are there any related articles? I totally understand what you said if it's true

Comment: Dunno, haven't found anything special from quick googling, maybe https://javascript.info/async-await? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447782/1048572

Comment: see https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-promises-async-await-5gke I think you're right

When the await keyword is met, the execution context of the foo function waits in the micro-task queue and consequently the call stack is empty, so after console.log('111) runs, the execution context of the foo function waiting in the micro-task queue goes back up to the call stack and runs again from where it was suspended

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help:

1. When foo() will start to execute it will create its execution context into callstack and when it encounter await the JS engine will suspend foo() execution and the execution context of foo() will get removed temporary from the callstack and now callstack is empty hence promise will get returned.
2. Later when the fetch() will return a fulfilled promise, the execution context will get created again for foo() and the next line will start to execute where foo() was suspended before. In your case it will start to execute from const data = ...
3. But in your case, the fetch() retuned a promise which is rejected hence you see 111 followed by  Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Answer (score 0):

Since your `foo()` is async, everything after `await` is executed async, so after `console.log('111')` which is sync. So use `await foo()` to wait for `foo()` to be settled (resolved or rejected) before `console.log('111')`. If you want to catch an error from `foo()` you should rethrow your error.

Regarding your question what happens with the call stack I wouldn't bother, but I would imagine `async/await` as substitution of `.then().catch()` so basically after `await` and in a `catch` block you have completely different functions placed in a call stack in the moment of their executions. The only problem that after `await` for example you have assess to variables defined before `await`. Consider it as magic of attaching one scope to another...

```js
async function foo() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://www.xxx.xxx");
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error!!: ", e);
        throw e;
      }
    }
(async() => {
    try{
       await foo();
    }catch(e){
       console.log(e.message);
    }
    console.log('111');
})();
```

Some scope magic:
[image]

```js
(async () => {

  const test = true;
  await new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve));
  debugger;

})();
```

Comment: I'm not saying that I want to make the error print out first.

When the foo function is called, the execution context of the foo function is created, added to the call stack, and when the network request is started in the background through fetch, the execution context of the foo function is removed from the call stack and console.log ('111) is executed.

But the execution context of the foo function has been removed, so how can there be an error in the catch inside the foo function.

Answer (score 0):

> In order for console.log('111) to run, the call stack must be empty, but how does the catch in the foo function that has already ended get an error??

You have it the wrong way around. The call stack has to be empty in order to continue from `await fetch()`

Comment: Of course, the global execution context exists in the call stack. When I said "the call stack is empty", it means the foo() function is terminated

Answer (score -1):

maybe this points can help you :

1. `console.log(111)` is called before `foo()` promise completion.
2. To catch thrown error of `foo()`, you need to add `.catch(err => ...)`
3. You need to throw the exception in the catch clause if you want to catch it externally, (or do not try-catch)

Note, you can add `await` before the call to foo in order to have sequential calls after, thus console.log(111) will be called after promise completion